# Error when trying to run a new react.js app on windows 10

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I get an error, when I try to run "npm start" after I have created a test app. I am on windows 10.
I should mention, that I'm new into js, but I have followed this guide:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-js-windows-setup/

I have tried to reinstall node.js and search on different websites, but without luck.

The error codes and log-file can be found on the two screen-shots below:

[log file,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJX1M.png)
[terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wY7x.png)

Thanks in advance!

/Esben

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you edit your post to include the text of your errors rather than screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: npm cache clean --force

Step 2: Delete node_modules by rm -r "node_modules" folder or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete. Delete package-lock.json file too.

Step 3: npm install

To start again,  npm start

Comment: Hi CuCu

Thank you for the quick answer!
 
I have tried the above steps, but without luck. Also I have tried to create a new app, moreover without luck. 

I will try to search for a solution .

/Esben